# After using a form POST how can I store the variable in session?

Tags: php, variables, session, post, store

Is this possible? I have sent a value using a form post and retrived in the php but if i refresh it disappears. Can this be stored?

Comment: like um: `$_SESSION['value']=$_POST['value']`

Comment: Just store the post array in session ans you can access every where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can store it in `SESSION`. Please read the following code:-

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Check Post variables are available
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    echo $_POST['username']." Username found in form <br />";
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username'];
    echo $_SESSION["username"]." stored in session <br />";;
}
else
    echo 'No, form submitted. Your old stored username was '.$_SESSION["username"];
    //echo 'No, form submitted.';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**To start session in `wordpress`**

Write below code in your functions.php

```
function register_my_session()
{
    if( !session_id() )
    {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Comment: as soon as i reload the page the value disappears. Does session start have to specifically be at the very top

Comment: Yes @jord49, you must start session at top of the page.

Comment: Realised it wasnt at the top of the page as i'm using Wordpress so have moved the session start into the header but its still not remembering the value. It's fine if i refresh but if I do a reload it disappears.

Comment: <?php
session_start(); 
?>  at the very top and then further down $_SESSION['newsession']=$_POST['username'];

$hello = $_SESSION["newsession"];

echo $hello;

Comment: Thanks but its still resetting. Header: <?php
session_start(); 
if(session_id() == '')
    session_start();
?> and then the code you put above with my variable name added

Comment: What if i store them when logging in before the form is posted does that make any difference?

Comment: Yes @jord49, It will give you warning message something like `undefined variable $_POST['variable']`. So I have add check before setting session variable. Please my answer again.

Comment: Thanks, have added that in but i'm just getting nothing. So it's not as if its undefined either :/

Comment: At the moment they're posted from index.html, to profile.php. Its outputting the variable fine and if i click refresh its still there, but if i reload it disappears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75618/discussion-between-dj-mha-and-jord49).

Answer (score 1):

```
// set session to start
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
session_start();


$_SESSION["newsession"]= $value;
$_SESSION['post_session'] = $_POST;
```

you can see documentation of session
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php