# Store session value in $_post

Tags: php, session, post

hi i know how to store `post` value into `session` but how can i store `session` value into post.
`post` into session

```
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
   $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
   $_SESSION['mno'] = $_POST['mno'];
   $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
```

I have an array stored in `session` and i want to `store` it into `post`.

Can i do this? If yes then how?

I want to store all `array` value in `post` from `session`

Comment: did you put session_start(); at the beggining of the file?

Comment: also look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725387/after-using-a-form-post-how-can-i-store-the-variable-in-session

Comment: yes....thats why my value stored in session

Comment: @boroboris they doing opposite....

Comment: @Vivek why are you planning to do this? Any specific reason?

Comment: well i want to pass value to another function that have `post` data which comes from another function or tpl file.

Comment: @Vivek You will end up with much better code if you decouple your functions to take their input as a parameter, and not directly access `$_POST`. See also [Why are Global Variables Evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is not a persistent store where you can put things. The point of `$_POST` is that it is populated *at the start of the request*, with the data that was passed *to* the server *from* the client (usually, web browser).

You *can* write into that array, but it won't have any special effect. It's just an array variable that's globally available in all scopes of your code. Normally, you'd just want to create a new array, and assign whatever you want in there:

```
$data = [];
$data['stored_foo'] = $_SESSION['foo'];
$data['submitted_foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
```

See also [Why are Global Variables Evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

If you want to send data *back* to the browser, you can:

- put it in the output (using `echo` etc)
- put it in an HTTP header (using the `header()` function)
- put it in a cookie (which will be sent as an HTTP header, crafted for you by the `setcookie()` function)

Comment: thankx for sharing this information. I usually think that we can insert `value` in `post` through `form` or `ajax`

Comment: @Vivek Yes, when you submit a form, or send an AJAX request, the browser sends some data to the server. That data is parsed by PHP and put into a new array called `$_POST`. On the next request, there will be different data (or possibly none) so `$_POST` will be created with different data each time.

Comment: my page goed blank when i do this `$_POST['profile'] = $_SESSION['profile'];`

Comment: @Vivek See this reference answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851

Answer (score 2):

The opposite should work without any problems.

```
   $_POST['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];
   $_POST['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
   $_POST['mno'] = $_SESSION['mno'];
   $_POST['age'] = $_SESSION['age'];
```

If you want to hold an array you can do it like this:

```
$datapost = array ( 'name' => $_SESSION['name'], 'email' => $_SESSION['email']);
$_POST['info'] = $datapost;
```

Comment: can i store array as well..? like this $_POST = $_SESSION['profile'];

Comment: Yes - $_POST can hold an array as well, no problem with that, but it's not advisable as the reason of $_POST is other.

Comment: @Vivek i updated the answer with an example of array saved into $_POST for your ease.

Comment: does value of post expires when we go to another page ot class..?

Comment: @Vivek yes - each time we have a new form posting something all values are regenerated from this form. If we dont have a new form post, then $_POST would simply not be set.

Comment: if i store value into post from session on every time when that method call.....is that good to store value